# Postgres-SQL multiple users in docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I just downloaded the latest postgressql docker image 12.12 and it's giving some user authentication errors. following part is not working on this new release. (this is working on postgres 10.5 docker image)
New version doesn't create Role with correct username/password.

```
 environment:
  - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  - USERS_AND_DBS=U1|U1|password U2|U2|password
```

When i run the container, it gives user can't authenticate (user U1 , DB U1/ user U2, DB U2 (password=password for both users on two DB's  ). Looks like some changes to the new container ?

Comment: That `USERS_AND_DBS` variable isn't one that's documented for the [`postgres` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres); do you have something else that processes it?

Comment: Please give the complete error message and a complete docker command and/or docker-compose file.

Comment: Thanks, added USERS_AND_DBS environment variable to the docker container to get those variables and create/db/roles using a shell script. Everything is working now. Thanks